# mysqli warning appearing stating that I have a null value in column

Tags: php, mysqli

Below I have a modules drop down menu where it gets a list of modules from the db an obviously displays them in a drop down menu. It also displays the selected module number and module name in the `$output` variable and in a hidden input (`$hiddenoutput`) it displays the module id of the selected module (This was successfully texted when text input was text before changing to hidden)

```
$active = 1;

 $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("i",$active);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);

 $modules = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

 $output = ""; 
 $hiddenoutput = "";
 $moduleHTML = "";  
 $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
 { 
     $moduleno = $dbModuleNo;
     $module = $dbModuleId;
     $modulename = $dbModuleName; 
     $moduleHTML .= "<option value='".$module."'>" . $moduleno . " - " . $modulename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

         if (isset($_POST['module']) && ($_POST['module'] == $module)) {
    $output .= "<p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> " . $moduleno .  " - "  . $modulename . "</p>";
    $hiddenoutput .= "<p><input type='hidden' id='hiddenoutput' name='hiddenmodule' value='". $module ."'></p>";
}
  } 

  $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

  $submittedModuleId = (isset($_POST['module'])) ? $_POST['module'] : '';
  $output = (isset($output)) ? $output : '';
  $hiddenoutput = (isset($hiddenoutput)) ? $hiddenoutput : '';
```

The details are displayed in the form below:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="errormsg"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></span><?php echo $hiddenoutput . $output; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

But what I really do not understand is that in my INSERT sql below, it is able to retrieve and insert all values except for one and that is the value of the Module Id displayed in the hidden input. It keeps stating:

`Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1048): Column 'ModuleId' cannot be null in ... on line 172`

What my question is that why is can not it retrieve and insert the value in the database for the module id? Below is the code:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['hiddenmodule'])) {

$_SESSION['hiddenmodule'] = $_POST['hiddenmodule'];

}

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

}

if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];

    }

if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}
else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    ++$_SESSION['sessionCount'];
}


$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];

if (isset($_POST['durationChosen'])) {

$_SESSION['durationChosen'] = $_POST['durationChosen'];

}

if (isset($_POST['dateChosen'])) {

$_SESSION['dateChosen'] = $_POST['dateChosen'];

}

if (isset($_POST['timeChosen'])) {

$_SESSION['timeChosen'] = $_POST['timeChosen'];

}

if (isset($_POST['textQuestion'])) {

$_SESSION['textQuestion'] = $_POST['textQuestion'];

}

if (isset($_POST['textMarks'])) {

$_SESSION['textMarks'] = $_POST['textMarks'];

}

if (isset($_POST['totalWeight'])) {

$_SESSION['totalWeight'] = $_POST['totalWeight'];

}

if (isset($_POST['buildings'])) {

$_SESSION['buildings'] = $_POST['buildings'];

}

if (isset($_POST['rooms'])) {

$_SESSION['rooms'] = $_POST['rooms'];

}

if (isset($_POST['teacherforename'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $_POST['teacherforename'];

}

if (isset($_POST['teachersurname'])) {

$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $_POST['teachersurname'];

}

if (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $_POST['teacherusername'];

}

var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SESSION);

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

$sql = "
  SELECT TeacherId
  FROM Teacher
  WHERE TeacherUsername = ?
";

if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

// Bind parameter for statement
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['teacherusername']);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

// This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
// variables before calling fetch()
$stmt->bind_result($teacherid);

// This populates $teacherid
$stmt->fetch();

// Close the statment
$stmt->close();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{

    $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

    for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; $i++) {

            $insertsql = "
      INSERT INTO Session
        (SessionName, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room)
      VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

        $sessname = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
        $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

        $insert->bind_param("sssisiiis", $sessname, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                     $_SESSION['totalWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                     $_SESSION['hiddenmodule'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

    }


}
```

Below is what the `var_dump($_SESSION)` outputs:

```
array(17) { 
["teacherid"]=> int(49) 
["teacherusername"]=> string(8) "u0867587" 
["teacherforename"]=> string(5) "Bruce" 
["teachersurname"]=> string(5) "Finch" 
["id"]=> string(5) "XNTLR" 
["initial_count"]=> string(1) "1" 
["sessionNum"]=> string(1) "1" 
["sessionCount"]=> int(1) 
["durationChosen"]=> string(22) "02 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs" 
["dateChosen"]=> string(10) "15-12-2012" 
["timeChosen"]=> string(5) "10:00" 
["textQuestion"]=> string(1) "1" 
["textMarks"]=> string(1) "5" 
["totalWeight"]=> string(1) "0" 
["buildings"]=> string(14) "Canalside East" 
["rooms"]=> string(7) "CE01/04" 
["hiddenmodule"]=> NULL }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because hiddenmodule is is not posted. See your var dump. Check the form with firebug to see if this input field is add

Comment: In my var_dump I know it doesn't show the Module heading, the input I changed to text and it is displayed on the page for definite. But it is not performing the $_POST in the other php script

Comment: Echo the session of hiddenmodule so you can see if it has a value. Also it is easier to help you if you put all data that you use for the insert.

Comment: code has been updated to show full code. The full code contains all the sessions and it contains a query to select the teacherid of the logged in teacher and below that is the insert where it inserts all details into the database. Nothing was echoed when I echoed hidden module so I did a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and you can see the whole output but hiddenmodule $_SESSION is `NULL`

Comment: That is the problem, the session should contain an id, but it is never set so the session will remain as null. So when you do a insert you get that error. So it looks like the hiddenmodule don't get posted.

Comment: That's my issue, how am i suppose to get it posted?

Comment: instead of $hiddenoutput .= try $hiddenoutput =

And remove this: $hiddenoutput = (isset($hiddenoutput)) ? $hiddenoutput : '';

I guess it has to work now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I had to do was move the $hiddenoutput echo into the other form to get it to work. Thanks for your help